# Importing Encog3.3 library to Eclipse via Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, encog

Trying to work with the Encog3.3 library for machine learning but couldn't import it to Eclipse.

The Quickstart Guide says:

> You might also be able to instruct your IDE to pull the Encog JAR from
>   Maven central:
>   http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22encog-core%22

How do i do that? Does anyone know any easier way?

Thanks

Comment: Can you also provide the link to the quickstart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.encog</groupId>
    <artifactId>encog-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This will add the `Encog3.3` library to your project.

Comment: Thank!! How do i access this pom.xml file?

Comment: You will have to create your own pom.xml file if you are using maven. See this [link](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html).